# Does Javascript converts numbers and other data types to strings to print it in console?

Tags: javascript

So I was reading a book on JS , and it says if you write

```
var x = 20;
console.log(x);
```

Then Javascript will first convert x to string implicitly then print it. Can't Javascript just print numbers on console ?

Comment: How would you define a "number" in a console?

Comment: The console prints text. Text is strings. So yes, technically speaking, it converts numbers to strings before printing, although it's worth noting that it does other things too, like making objects be expandable, or putting strings in quotes if you're logging multiple things. It's a bit more complicated, but really it doesn't matter; it's JavaScript after all!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log - `The string representations of each of these objects are appended together in the order listed and output.`

Comment: typeof() should give you the type of the object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book isn't quite right. Unless you deliberately concatenate with a string, the console will generally log the argument *as-is*. Numbers will be logged as numbers, strings will be logged as strings, objects will be logged as (expandable, navigable) objects, and so on.

```js
console.log(20);
console.log('20');
```

results in

[image]

You need good eyes to notice it, but logged numbers are displayed distinctly differently from strings; the console hasn't converted everything into a string.

On the other hand, if you did something that *did* happen to involve coercing expressions to strings beforehand, eg:

```
console.log('Value is: ' + someValue);
```

That *would* result in `someValue`, no matter its type, being coerced to a string first. But that's not because of the console, but because `+` concatenates the expressions together before passing the result as an argument to the console.